# css how to make the background image padding to right

Tags: css

I have this css

```
#div ul li:hover{
    background-image:  url(http://localhost/mywebsite/public/images/close.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    background-color: #ccccff;
}
```

the `close.png` image is small icon, but i becomse at the edge , i want to make it to the right a little bet, i means like if the div has padding to the right, i hope i could make my question clear, sorry i am bad on english

Comment: Use percent like 95% instead of right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use

```
#div ul li:hover{
    background-position: top 95%;
}
```

Comment: I'm not very sure due to the hard to read English, but isn't it that he want's it to be `background-position: right 95%;`?

Comment: what does this code do? what if we want to have 5% margin from all the 4 sides?